# Is the creator of a flag stored in the database?

Tags: 7, flags

Is the uid of the user who created a specific flag stored in the database? Where is it stored?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's stored in the `flag_content` table, in the `uid` column which is defined as

> The user ID by whom this content was flagged.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that's not what I meant! I meant the user who created the flag itself, rather than the user who specified whether that flag should be set for a specific piece of content.

Comment: Ah...in that case I think you're out of luck, the `flags` table doesn't have a `uid` column unfortunately

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't see one: I was wondering whether there was something in the "options" field that indicated a flag's creator. Looks like I might have to write a module to bolt this on.

Comment: Doesn't look like there is, the options field looks to contain higher-level meta data for the flag. I think you're right that a custom solution would be the best way forward

Comment: Thanks @Clive; yeah, one of the module's developers has confirmed as much on the module's issue queue. I've started writing the code to add a uid field to the flags table; the API that flag.module provides looks pretty rich so I'll see how I get on